# How to prove Gauss-Seidel companion matrix for inverse of a SPD matrix has spectral radius less than 1?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have been asked to prove the following:

Let $A$ be a symmetric, positive definite matrix and let $B=A^{-1}$ be its inverse. Then we decompose $B$ into the Gauss-Seidel companion matrix $C$, $C=-(B_L+B_D)^{-1}B_U$ where $B_L$ is the lower triangular component of $B$, $B_D$ the diagonal component, and $B_U$ the upper triangular. Prove $\rho(C)<1$ where $\rho(C)$ is the spectral radius of $C$.

How can I show this? My numerical linear algebra background is fairly limited; I didn't even know of the notion of spectral radius until this came up.

Comment: GS method converges for SPD matrices and an inverse of an SPD matrix is SPD as well.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Could you expand a bit more perhaps with the math? How can we use what you said to get at the spectral radius?